# Cannot load data in server-side processing in DataTable.js jquery plug-in

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I just started learning DataTable.js and I've got one doubt regarding server-side processing in DataTable.js, that is, how can I load the table in server-side processing?

I'm posting my code here so it would be easy to understand

**table.html**

```html
<table id="empTable">
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**script.js**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var empTable;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    empTable = $("#empTable").dataTable({
      'processing':true,
      'serverside':true,
      'ajax': 'fetchRecord.php'
    });
  });
</script>
```

**fetchRecord.php**

```php
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','example');
if($conn->connect_error) die("Could not connect".$conn->connect_error);

$fetchQuery = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phonenumber FROM employee";

$output = array('data' => array());

$result = $conn->query($fetch);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assco()){
    $output['data'][] = $row;
  }
}

$conn->close();

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Please tell me what's wrong with this code and how can I fetch data from php page and load it in DataTable?

Apologies for any mistakes.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `$result = $conn->query($fetch);` $fetch is undefined . You need to pass here `$fetchQuery` it would be `$result = $conn->query($fetchQuery);`

Comment: Thank you @Saty for pointing it out, my bad. But, still its not displaying data.

Comment: change `$output = array('data' => array());` to `$output = array();`

Comment: I found out the error. But thanks for helping @Saty.

Comment: Uuhm, the error would resolve with @Saty 's comment. I recommend enabling notices in `error_reporting()`. You would have figured that one out without spending the time to write the question... If a comment was helpful, at least have the courtesy to upvote.